# Details on HCI filter socket options?

Tags: python, c, sockets, bluetooth, hci

While I was testing some basic HCI commands using python's `socket` library, it seems that in order to get any socket traffic using `AF_BLUETOOTH` and `BTPROTO_HCI` a "pass all" filter needs to be set in the socket options:

```python
from socket import socket, AF_BLUETOOTH, SOCK_RAW, BTPROTO_HCI, SOL_HCI, HCI_FILTER
from struct import pack

PASS_ALL = pack("IIIh2x", 0xffffffff, 0xffffffff, 0xffffffff, 0)

def open_socket_with_hci(dev_id: int):
    hci = socket(AF_BLUETOOTH, SOCK_RAW, BTPROTO_HCI)
    hci.bind((dev_id,))
    hci.setsockopt(SOL_HCI, HCI_FILTER, PASS_ALL)
    return hci
```

I found [hci_filter](http://gbrault.github.io/gattclient/structhci__filter.html) struct defined as:

```c
struct hci_filter {
    uint32_t type_mask;
    uint32_t event_mask[2];
    uint16_t opcode;
};
```

The opcode mask is straight forward enough. I'm assuming `type_mask` is a mask on values (code from [hci.h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/62393dbcbe0f3001691e4bd479a25beb5941f2ed/include/net/bluetooth/hci.h#L288)):

```c
/* HCI data types */
#define HCI_COMMAND_PKT     0x01
#define HCI_ACLDATA_PKT     0x02
#define HCI_SCODATA_PKT     0x03
#define HCI_EVENT_PKT       0x04
#define HCI_DIAG_PKT        0xf0
#define HCI_VENDOR_PKT      0xff
```

But could someone please explain the 2x `event_mask`s? Is the 1st for HCI Event Type and the 2nd for Subevent Type (i.e. LE Meta Event)?

Comment: Quick note, there are two "different" sets of HCI commands, one for BT classic and one for BT LE. You need to specify whether you are using ble, bt classic or both. I'm assuming the API you're using supports both.

Answer (score 2):

So, I was looking through the [noble](https://github.com/noble/noble/) [source](https://github.com/noble/noble/blob/c4cd18a7a429bb832f6c4ca793be3faf9af884e9/lib/hci-socket/hci.js#L130) and found this:

```js
Hci.prototype.setSocketFilter = function() {
  var filter = new Buffer(14);
  var typeMask = (1 << HCI_COMMAND_PKT) | (1 << HCI_EVENT_PKT) | (1 << HCI_ACLDATA_PKT);
  var eventMask1 = (1 << EVT_DISCONN_COMPLETE) | (1 << EVT_ENCRYPT_CHANGE) | (1 << EVT_CMD_COMPLETE) | (1 << EVT_CMD_STATUS);
  var eventMask2 = (1 << (EVT_LE_META_EVENT - 32));
  var opcode = 0;

  filter.writeUInt32LE(typeMask, 0);
  filter.writeUInt32LE(eventMask1, 4);
  filter.writeUInt32LE(eventMask2, 8);
  filter.writeUInt16LE(opcode, 12);

  debug('setting filter to: ' + filter.toString('hex'));
  this._socket.setFilter(filter);
};
```

So the mask is defined as the bit shifted left by the constant's value defined in the Bluetooth Core Volume 2, Part E, Section 5 & 7.